# jQuery progress bar jumps to 100%

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have got this set up:

> HTML

```
 <div id="tst_loader"></div>
```

> JAVASCRIPT

```
$.ajax({
    xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                //Do something with upload progress here
        $('#tst_loader').html(percentComplete * 100 + '%');
            }
       }, false);

       xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
           if (evt.lengthComputable) {
               var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
               //Do something with download progress
            $('#tst_loader').html(percentComplete * 100 + '%');
           }
       }, false);

       return xhr;
    },
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: {feed:""},
    success: function(data){
        //Do something on success

     alert('done');
    }
```

> the PHP code:

```
<?php

$_POST['feed'] = 'http://www.cs.washington.edu/research/xmldatasets/data/tpc-h/orders.xml';/// A little heavier file for testing


                $dom = new DOMDocument; 
                $dom->load($_POST['feed']);

if(false !== $dom){

$use_errors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 
                        $s = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
                        libxml_clear_errors();
                        libxml_use_internal_errors($use_errors);
                        //libxml_disable_entity_loader( $oldDisable );

                        if(false !==    $s){    
$ctr = 0;
foreach ($s->channel->item as $item) {

  $out[$ctr]=$item->title;

$ctr++; 
}

echo json_encode( $out);

}


}




        ?>
```

Whenever the code is run, the `progressbar` immediately jumps to `100%` even though the `RSS FEED` is still being fetched .... in other words, there is no progress showing. All seems great but it keeps jumping... Any Idea how to achieve this??... Thank You!

**EDIT:** : Changed the link to something a little heavier : http://www.cs.washington.edu/research/xmldatasets/data/tpc-h/orders.xml

Comment: Is the `event.lengthComputable`? For a PHP script, the answer is normally no, unless you explicitly specify the `Content-Length` header.

Comment: Could still use XMLHTTPRequest2 on later browsers

Comment: @Chris how to **specify** the `Content-Length` ?.... any idea?... You can post it as an answer to be possibly accepted. thx

Comment: It's not hard to do, but in this case it will likely have little benefit. It won't tell you how long until your server finishes downloading the BBC RSS feed. In fact your progress bar will stay at 0 during all of that code. The only thing it will measure is the number of bytes that the browser is expecting from the server and the number of bytes it has received. If you are still interested despite those caveats I am happy to post an answer anyway though.

Comment: @Chris  Sure... I'd higly appreciate!... Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments to the question, the way to set a `Content-Length` header (although in this case it's not that useful) would be to replace your `echo json_encode( $out);` with this:

```
$content = json_encode($out);
header("Content-Length: ".strlen($content));
echo $content;
```

Comment: Thanks, though I still can't see it loading... The New XML file I put has about 5MB but, it is not loading it sticks to 100%... Am using Firefox and tried on Chrome as well still not loading though :(

Comment: @UniversalGrasp Like I said in the comment on the question. The time it takes to load the XML is completely irrelevant. The progress bar will stick at 0 for that entire time. The only thing that you can calculate using standard AJAX progress is the progress transferring the final output from the server to the client.

Comment: You mean there is absolutely no way?... :(

Comment: It's not that there is no way of doing it, it's just a lot more complex than the code you already have. The best way would be to use a WebSocket that periodically sends progress updates to the client, followed by the final data when it is ready. This obviously makes the solution massively more complicated though.

Comment: Sure... thanks for the thought, but I have no choice but to be upto the task... I have already spend like over _Seven Hours_ banging my head over this......... I would'nt mind the  _complexity of the solution_... just hint me if you hv anything in mind

Comment: @UniversalGrasp Okay then. You will need to make a separate WebSocket process that runs on your server. This can be done in PHP with [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) but it's potentially easier to do in other languages since PHP is very much designed to be single threaded. You use JavaScript to connect to the WebSocket and then when that happens you begin downloading the XML file in a separate thread along with a progress callback (see `CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION`), and sends progress to the client. When the download is done you then want to send your data too.

Comment: let me try that.. still open to other thoughts though.....  just incase....Thanksyou....